# Did Zhang Zongchang order each player in a basketball game be given their own ball?

Tags: history, china

There is a claim that Chinese warlord, [Zhang Zongchang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhang_Zongchang) was confused by the sport of basketball:

[iFunny](https://ifunny.co/picture/authoritarian-after-seeing-a-basketball-game-for-the-first-time-Azm4ypNs7)

> After seeing a basketball game for the first time, he allegedly asked "Why the hell are they fighting over a single ball? We're the hosts. Are we seriously this poor?" He ordered all the players be given a basketball.

The claim is repeated on [Novel Updates blog](https://forum.novelupdates.com/posts/6879753/), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/ckk7ok/til_when_chinese_warlord_zhang_zongchang_saw_his/) and elsewhere, but I can find no primary source.

Comment: The quote makes it sound like he was not only unfamiliar with basketball, but unfamiliar with the entire concept of a sport where teams compete for control of a single ball.  That seems especially unlikely given how many different sports work like that.  https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-35409594 suggests that football-like sports already existed in ancient China.